# Defining function with arguments in a specific pattern similar to Graphics[]

Tags: graphics, function-construction, sequence, argument-patterns, arguments

I'm trying to define a function that is of this form:

```
f1[gr_,clr_] := Graphics@Style[gr,clr]

f2[gr1_, clr1_, gr2_, clr2_ (*etc*)] := Show[{f1[gr1,clr1], f1[gr2,clr2] (*etc*)}, "showOpts"]
```

Ηere, `gr` is a defined graphic, and `clr` is a color. I'm trying to have the arguments in `f2` not require braces, just like one would use arguments in `Graphics`. I already have options for `Show` that are the same for every iteration of `f1`, but I'm having trouble with sequencing this one. `

Comment: `f2 = List /* OperatorApplied[Partition][2] /* Map[Apply[f1]] /* Show`.

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely follow.  `Graphics` takes one argument, a list of styles and objects, not a var-arg"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f1, f2]
f1[gr_, clr_] := Graphics@Style[gr, clr]

f2[args : __, opts : OptionsPattern[Show]] := Show[f1 @@@ Partition[{args}, 2], opts]
```

***Example:***

```
f2[Disk[{2, 2}, 1], Red, 
 Annulus[{1, 1}, 1/2], Blue, 
 Rectangle[{0, 2}], Green, 
 ImageSize -> 400, Frame -> True]
```

[image]